# How can I set UIView background in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors, appearance

I am trying to set the background color of UIView programmatically. The code I am using is

```
UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
```

It works fine when I open the app, but as soon as I interact with it, the entire screen becomes a block of the selected color:[image: what I see]

Comment: The problem is that `UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue` makes _every_ new view blue, forever after. Every view. Buttons. Labels. Everything. So yes, it is like spraying blue all over the interface.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to give this view an outlet for example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
```

Then you can use this:

```
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

but the previous should be written in your

```
viewDidLoad()
```

so finally your code will be like that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```